# How can I have a loader bar when changing routes in AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs

YouTube has this crazy cool feature when you change videos there's a bar to indicate page loading. Using `AngularJS`, how can I have the same effect?

[image]

Comment: You need to find (or make) a directive to do that.  Do you have an open-source one that's not Angular?  If so it probably wouldn't be too hard to wrap a directive around it.

Comment: where's the code that represents an attempt?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a good start: https://github.com/chieffancypants/angular-loading-bar

It has an interceptor that displays the bar when an XHR is triggered, you could change it so that it shows the bar on $routeChangeStart and hides it on $routeChangeSuccess.

Answer (score 0):

**PACE** is good for you, it is more than what you want;

http://github.hubspot.com/pace/docs/welcome/

or you can use **Loadingbar.js**;

http://www.onextrapixel.com/2013/09/02/loadingbar-js-adding-a-youtube-like-loading-bar-to-your-website/